# Periodic Callback from Thread in Python

Tags: python

My program calls a method `baz` in a new thread from my `spam` method.

Now I need to check the value of self.track every second from within this new thread.

```
import threading
class A(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, player):
    self.track = True

def Baz(self):
    // how do i check the value of self.track every 1 second here
    while self.track:
        // do something


def Spam(self):
    player_thread = Thread(target=self.Baz)
    player_thread.start()
```

How do I check it, say every one second ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to poll, just use `time.sleep` inside the loop.

```
import time
...
    while self.track:
        time.sleep(1)
```

If you want more accuracy, for instance if you are doing other operations inside the loop that take non-trivial amounts of time you can do:

```
...
while self.track:
    start = time.time()
    # Do things here
    sleep_time = start-time.time() + 1
    if sleep_time > 0:
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
```

You could also come at this from another angle all together if you are looking to block the thread until `self.track` is set to `True`, and all the workers will be created before that happens.

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self, player):
        self._track = False
        self.player = player
        self._track_condition = threading.Condition()
    @property
    def track(self):
        return self._track
    @track.setter(self, value):
        if value:
            self._track_condition.acquire()
            self._track_condition.notify_all()
            self._track_condition.release()
        self._track = value
   def baz(self):
       self._track_condition.acquire()
       self._track_condition.wait()
       self._track_condition.release()
       while self.track:
           # Do stuff
   def spam(self):
       player_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.baz)
       player_thread.start()
```

I would note though that unless your player actions are I/O bound, `threading` is probably not going to do much for performance, and may even hurt it.  `threading.Thread`s all live within the [GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), so they can't actually execute simultaneously in parallel.  If you want that, you need [`multiprocessing`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).

Answer (score 3):

You check, then sleep for one second, in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `time.sleep` :

```
from time import sleep

def Baz(self):
    // Will check self.track each second until it becomes true
    while not self.track:
        sleep(1)

    while self.track:
        //do something
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may want to read a bit about the [`select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) api. This is often better than using periodic probing.

Comment: I'll admit I'm not 100% sure on this, but I think at least on some platforms, `time.sleep()` is actually implemented under the hood with OS-level `select`.